# how do you allow javascript communications with Flex/Flash/Actionscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, sockets, flash, apache-flex

Well here's a problem.

I've got a website with large javascript backend.  This backend talks to a server over a socket with a socket bridge using http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/

The socket "bridge" is a Flex/Flash .swf application/executable/plugin/thing for which the source is missing.

I've got to change it.

More facts:

```
file appExePluginThing.swf
appExePluginThing.swf Macromedia Flash data (compressed), version 9
```

I've used https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/ to decompile the .swf file and I think I've sorted out what's the original code vs the libraries and things Flash/Flex built into it.

I've used FDT (the free version) to rebuild the decompiled code into MYappExePluginThing.swf so I can run it with the javascript code and see what happens.

I'm here because what happens isn't good.  Basically, my javascript code (MYjavascript.js) gets to the point where it does

```
    window.log("init()");
    var so = new SWFObject("flash/MYappExePluginThing.swf"", socketObjectId, "0", "0", "9", "#FFFFFF");
    window.log("init() created MYappExecPluginThing!!!");
    so.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "always");
    log("init() added Param!!");
    so.write(elId);
    log("init() wrote!");
```

IE9's console (yeah, you read that right) shows

```
init()
created MYappExecPluginThing!!!
init() added Param!!
init() wrote!
```

but none of the debugging i've got in MYappExePluginThing.as displays and nothing else happens.

I'm trying to figure out what I've screwed up/what's going on?  Is MYappExePluginThing.as running?  Is it waiting on something?  Did it fail?  Why aren't the log messages in MYappExePluginThing.as showing up?

The first most obvious thing is I'm using FDT which, I suspect, was not used to build the original.  Is there some kind of magic "build javascript accessible swf thing" in FlashBuilder or some other IDE?

First noteworthy thing I find is:

```
file MYappExePluginThing.swf
MYappExePluginThing.swf  Macromedia Flash data (compressed), version 14
```

I'm using Flex 4.6 which, for all I know, may have a completely different mechanism for allowing javascript communication than was used in appExePluginThing.swf

Does anyone know if that's true?

For example, when FDT runs this thing (I can compile but FDT does not create a .swf unless i run it) I get a warning in the following method:

```
  private function init() : void
  {
 Log.log("console.log", "MYappExePluginThing init()");
             //var initCallback:String = Application.application.parameters.initCallback?Application.application.parameters.initCallback:"MYjavascript.MYappExePluginThing_init";
     var initCallback:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.initCallback?FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.initCallback:"MYjavascript.MYappExePluginThing_init";
     try
     {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("method1Callback",method1);
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("method2Callback",method2);
        ExternalInterface.call(initCallback);
     }
     catch(err:Error)
     {
        Log.log("console.log", "MYappExePluginThing init() ERROR err="+err);
     }
  }
```

I got a warning that Application.application was deprecated and I should change:

```
     var initCallback:String = Application.application.parameters.initCallback?Application.application.parameters.initCallback:"MYjavascript.MYappExePluginThing_init";
```

to:

```
var initCallback:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.initCallback?FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.initCallback:"MYjavascript.MYappExePluginThing_init";
```

which I did but which had no effect on making the thing work.

(FYI Log.log() is something I added:

```
    public class Log{

        public static function log(dest:String, mssg:String):void{
                if(ExternalInterface.available){
                  try{
                    ExternalInterface.call(dest, mssg);
          }
          catch(se:SecurityError){
          }
          catch(e:Error){
          }
                }
        trace(mssg);            
         }

              }
```

)

Additionally, in MYjavascript.js MYappExePluginThing_init looks like this:

```
this.MYappExePluginThing_init = function () {
    log("MYjavascript.js - MYappExePluginThing_init:");
};
```

Its supposed to be executed when MYappExePluginThing finishes initializing itself.

Except its not.  The message is NOT displaying on the console.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any references explaining how you allow javascript communication in Flex 4.6 so I can check if I've got this structured correctly.

Is it a built in kind of thing all Flex/Flash apps can do?  Is my swf getting accessed?  Is it having some kind of error?  Is it unable to communicate back to my javascript?

Does anyone have any links to references?

If this was YOUR problem, what would you do next?

Comment: The first thing I would do: add a textfield to your stage or root mc and set its *text* property in your Log.log() function. trace() doesn't serve you (unless you are logging it, which I assume you are not as you didn't mention it). In that way you can clearly see whether some Error (as far as I know only SecurityError is thrown, so you don't need to catch both) is thrown and whether the function is called at all! - maybe there is an error thrown before calling it and it never gets to call the ExternalInterface.

Comment: @Fygo i don't understand what you mean by "stage or root mc".  can you explain?

Comment: @Fygo does mc mean movie clip?  this isn't a movie clip.  its an ActionScript wrapper exposing part of the Flex api for use from javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have never worked with Flex so I may be wrong here (so take it with a grain of salt) but as far as I know the top level object must be a descendant of Sprite, both mx Application and Spark Application. In that case it is a display object. How do you actually trace whether you are getting some error etc.? You cannot run it without the browser. Are you logging the trace() to some file then?

Comment: The swf I'm working with exposes the Socket api to my JavaScript.  It provides event callbacks that pass data back to the JavaScript and methods to accept data from the JavaScript.  There's no visual content unless that's some AS3/flex requirement of which I'm unaware (and that's completely possible)

Comment: We are going around in circles here. :) I understand there is no visual content (yet) and it serves only as middle man. What does your main (document) class extend?

Comment: It extends Application

Comment: So a descendant of a display object. Create a new textfield or something that can display content. Add it in your Application's constructor. Instead of trace, set the text of the textfield. HTML: Increase your swf size to something "visible". Add it to your html so it is visible. Or just look up how to log the trace() to a file (more complicated, as far as I remember)

Answer (score 0):

(Not a full solution but I ran out of room in the comment section.)

To answer your basic question, there's nothing special you should need to do to allow AS3-to-JS communication beyond what you've shown. However, you may have sandbox security issues on localhost; to avoid problems, set your SWFs as local-trusted (right-click Flash Player > Global Settings > Advanced > Trusted Location Settings). I'm guessing this *not* your problem, though, because you'd normally get a sandbox violation error.

More likely IMO is that something is broken due to decompilation and recompilation. SWFs aren't meant to do that, it's basically a hack made mostly possible due to SWF being an open format.

What I suggest is that you debug your running SWF. Using break-points and stepping through the code you should be able to narrow down where things are going wrong. You can also more easily see any errors your SWF is throwing.

Comment: i'm hosting this on a Mac and accessing it from IE9 running on a Windows machine.  on which system should i set the SWF as local-trusted - Mac or Windows?  

regarding decompilation/recompilation causing problems, do you mean its possible the decompiled source needs to be edited and cleaned up in some fashion?  i'm no flex expert but the decompiled code looked unlike any of the flex code i've ever seen.

i'd love to use the running SWF - the problem is i have to modify it due to a bug.

Comment: Ah, so you are accessing the Mac through an http server? In that case it's already running in the network sandbox so it should be fine. Debugging will be trickier, though, you'll need to setup a "remote debugging session". Check online for instructions on that. As for decompiling, my suggestion is that the decompiled code is simply not working the same as the original code. Flex compiles down to intermediary AS3, which compiles down to ABC, so you will never reverse it back to the original code exactly. Some errors could have been introduced in the decompiling.

Comment: yes my Mac is acting as the server and my Windows machine is acting as the client.  a remote debugging session sounds like a great big pain - shouldn't i be able to get log messages to IE9's console?  the other full blown swf application logs to the console via the code i posted so i was hoping i could reuse that.

Comment: i was afraid that you meant the decompiler introduced cr@p.  but that's also not too bad - the action the swf performs is pretty simple.  i can strip out the stuff that looks REALLY strange (hoping it was added by the decompiler) and at least have the bulk of the source.  or i could rewrite the whole d@mn thing altogether which is looking like a distinct possibility ;-)

Comment: Your actual log code looks just fine. So the thing is Flex compiles Flex source to intermediary AS3 before it gets compiled to ABC in a SWF, so the decompiler will turn the ABC into AS3, but not the original Flex source (unless it knows how to recognize Flex intermediary AS3 and turn it into Flex source, which I highly doubt but might be possible)... which, when compiled again with Flex, will again compile the already intermediary AS3 into intermediary AS3 again, possible breaking the intended behavior. So yes, major cleanup or re-write is probably required. :)

Comment: any links to debug an swf from FDT when its invoked by javascript?  i can get an external viewer to pop up but that's not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but an idea to get you started is to start logging everything on the Flash side to see where the breakage is.
Since you're using IE, I recommend getting the Debug flash player, installing it, then running Vizzy along side to show your traces.

Should give you a good idea of where the app is breaking down.

- [Vizzy](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/)
- [Debug Player](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/17/flashplayer_17_ax_debug.exe)